# Difference in types of token

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, access-token

I am hearing continously `token name` of different type. Can anybody explain me different type of `token` with some example.

```
Access token
Refresh token
Oauth Token
Bearer token
JWT token.
```

Please forgive me if my question is incorrect. I am highly consfused so looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right, terminology can be very confusing. [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) is the protocol to allow a client to get an access token to access the user's data on a resource server. The protocol is token agnostic (meaning it does not specify how the token looks). So OAuth token and access token are used interchangeably.

Often, the access token used in the protocol is a structured token in the JSON Web Token ([JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) format. It contains claims (name-value pairs) with info about the user and authentication that the resource server can use.

A bearer token is any token that can be used as the sole way of authenticating. If you have the token, you get access as the user for which it was issued. Nothing else required. OAuth2 typically uses bearer tokens, although some holder-of-key tokens (where you need to prove you acquired the token by signing something) are being added to the protocol. JWT tokens are usually bearer tokens.

[Refresh tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) are used in some OAuth2 protocol flows to allow the client to get a new access token when the issued one expires without asking the user to log in again. They are typically just an identifier to some row in the data store of the authorization server.